# How to remove all characters after dot in folder name on Windows

Tags: windows, command-line

I need to rename all folders and subfolders by removing these numbers and dots. But I can only use tools already present in Windows (I can't install or run third-party programs on the costumer machine).

I saw some similar cases here on the site, but I tried and it didn't work.

How can I do that?

Below is a screenshot of a list of folder items displayed in the Windows file manager. The full path shown for the parent folder is This PC, drive D, copia_config. Several folders listed under the parent folder have no extension, while the remaining folders have a title consisting of a primary folder name, a dot, then a long series of numbers, all as one name, without spaces.

> [image: Screenshot.]

Comment: Please when talking about similar cases always include a link to them in your question. Try powershell: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574648/use-regex-powershell-to-rename-files

Comment: Are you sure this folders are beeing used or not if yes you have to close the programs that might be using them first...

Comment: Good point, however I assume the word 'copia' in the folder name implies they're not in active use :)

Comment: I received those folders from server A to move to server B. In server B I have the same folder structure, but wihtout dots and numbers. For that resom I need remove those dots and numbers, because when I move folders windows will replace the files.

Comment: @Souza are you Brazilian like me?

Comment: @RicardoBohner yes. Sorry for my poor English...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the main folder open a command prompt and use this command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1* delims=." %a in ('dir /ad /on /b /s *.* ^|find /i "." ^|sort /r') do ren "%a.%b" "%~nxa"
```

[image: Image. An animated screenshot displaying example results of using the Windows command given above.]

Comment: That worked fine. Thank you.

Comment: I really don´t know how to write thoses scripts.... I need to learn.

Comment: It's pretty useful to automate stuff, and can save you loads of time with repetitive tasks like these (imagine renaming them manually). I'd get started with Windows PowerShell rather than oldfashioned batch scripting though.

Comment: Yes, if you starting now better go with powershell instead of batch (command line)